# Efficient implementation of Damerau-Levenshtein distance

Tags: performance, clojure, levenshtein-distance

I'm trying to implement really efficient Clojure function to compute [Damerau-Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance). I've decided to use   [this algorithm](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13525/Fast-memory-efficient-Levenshtein-algorithm) (attached source should be C++) for computing Levenshtein distance and add some lines to make it work for DLD.

Here is what I've created in Common Lisp (I hope it could help):

```
(defun damerau-levenshtein (x y)
  (declare (type string x y)
           #.*std-opts*)
  (let* ((x-len (length x))
         (y-len (length y))
         (v0 (apply #'vector (mapa-b #'identity 0 y-len)))
         (v1 (make-array (1+ y-len) :element-type 'integer))
         (v* (make-array (1+ y-len) :element-type 'integer)))
    (do ((i 0 (1+ i)))
        ((= i x-len) (aref v0 y-len))
      (setf (aref v1 0) (1+ i))
      (do ((j 0 (1+ j)))
          ((= j y-len))
        (let* ((x-i (char x i))
               (y-j (char y j))
               (cost (if (char-equal x-i y-j) 0 1)))
          (setf (aref v1 (1+ j)) (min (1+ (aref v1 j))
                                      (1+ (aref v0 (1+ j)))
                                      (+  (aref v0 j) cost)))
          (when (and (plusp i) (plusp j))
            (let ((x-i-1 (char x (1- i)))
                  (y-j-1 (char y (1- j)))
                  (val (+ (aref v* (1- j)) cost)))
              (when (and (char-equal x-i y-j-1)
                         (char-equal x-i-1 y-j)
                         (< val (aref v1 (1+ j))))
                (setf (aref v1 (1+ j)) val))))))
      (rotatef v* v0 v1))))
```

Now, I fear I cannot translate it into really efficient and idiomatic Clojure code (in functional style?). I would really appreciate any suggestion and I think it may be quite useful for many future readers too.

P.S. I've found [this implementation](http://clojuredocs.org/incanter/incanter.stats/damerau-levenshtein-distance), but I doubt if it is efficient and it uses some obsolete `contrib` functions (`deep-merge-with` and `bool-to-binary`):

```
(defn damerau-levenshtein-distance
  [a b]
  (let [m (count a)
        n (count b)
        init (apply deep-merge-with (fn [a b] b)
                    (concat
                     ;;deletion
                     (for [i (range 0 (+ 1 m))]
                       {i {0 i}})
                     ;;insertion
                     (for [j (range 0 (+ 1 n))]
                       {0 {j j}})))
        table (reduce
               (fn [d [i j]]
                 (deep-merge-with
                  (fn [a b] b)
                  d
                  (let [cost (bool-to-binary (not (= (nth a (- i 1))
                                          (nth b (- j 1)))))
                        x
                          (min
                           (+ ((d (- i 1))
                               j) 1) ;;deletion
                           (+ ((d i)
                               (- j 1)) 1) ;;insertion
                           (+ ((d (- i 1))
                               (- j 1)) cost)) ;;substitution))
                        val (if (and (> i 1)
                               (> j 1)
                               (= (nth a (- i 1))
                                  (nth b (- j 2)))
                               (= (nth a (- i 2))
                                  (nth b (- j 1))))
                        (min x (+ ((d (- i 2))
                                   (- j 2)) ;;transposition
                                  cost))
                        x)]
                    {i {j val}})))
               init
               (for [j (range 1 (+ 1 n))
                     i (range 1 (+ 1 m))] [i j]))]
    ((table m) n)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this should do the trick (based on [KIMA's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25771676/3687048)):

```
(defn da-lev [str1 str2]
  (let [l1 (count str1)
        l2 (count str2)
        mx (new-matrix :ndarray (inc l1) (inc l2))]
   (mset! mx 0 0 0)
   (dotimes [i l1]
     (mset! mx (inc i) 0 (inc i)))
   (dotimes [j l2]
     (mset! mx 0 (inc j) (inc j)))
   (dotimes [i l1]
     (dotimes [j l2]
       (let [i+ (inc i) j+ (inc j)
             i- (dec i) j- (dec j)
             cost (if (= (.charAt str1 i)
                         (.charAt str2 j))
                    0 1)]
         (mset! mx i+ j+
                (min (inc (mget mx i j+))
                     (inc (mget mx i+ j))
                     (+ (mget mx i j) cost)))
         (if (and (pos? i) (pos? j)
                  (= (.charAt str1 i)
                     (.charAt str2 j-))
                  (= (.charAt str1 i-)
                     (.charAt str2 j)))
           (mset! mx i+ j+
                  (min (mget mx i+ j+)
                       (+ (mget mx i- j-) cost)))))))
   (mget mx l1 l2)))
```

Please note that you need [`core.matrix`](https://github.com/mikera/core.matrix) library, which is not standard (despite its name). One can install it with Leiningen this way:

```
[net.mikera/core.matrix "0.29.1"]
```

The library lives in namespace `clojure.core.matrix`. To use this solution 'as is' you should 'add' symbols from the namespace into your namespace.

Answer (score 3):

I recently had to write an efficient levenshtein distance function in clojure to calculate the edits between a ground truth text and a ocr engine result.
The recursive implementation wasn't performant enough to quickly calculate the levenshtein distance between two whole pages, so my implementation uses dynamic programming. 
Instead of dropping down to java 2d-arrays it uses core.matrix to handle the matrix stuff. 
Adding the transposition stuff for damerau-levenshtein should not be hard.

```
(defn lev [str1 str2]
  (let [mat (new-matrix :ndarray (inc (count str1)) (inc (count str2)))
        len1 (count str1) len2 (count str2)]
   (mset! mat 0 0 0)
   (dotimes [i lein1]
     (mset! mat (inc i) 0 (inc i)))
   (dotimes [j len2]
     (mset! mat 0 (inc j) (inc j)))
   (dotimes [dj len2]
     (dotimes [di len1]
       (let [j (inc dj) i (inc di)]
         (mset! mat i j
              (cond
                (= (.charAt ^String str1 di) (.charAt ^String str2 dj))
                (mget mat di dj)
                :else
                (min (inc (mget mat di j)) (inc (mget mat i dj))
                    (inc (mget mat di dj))))))))
   (mget mat len1 len2))))
```

Hope this helps